# Need to Store Jmeter results into MySql database

Tags: mysql, jmeter

I have tried to store Jmeter results into mysql database but am getting below error.
"**Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides**"

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to import [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) with test results into MySQL table using [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) statement you will need to enable data loading via setting `local_infile` global variable to `1` like:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

More information: [Security Considerations for LOAD DATA LOCAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local-security.html)

If you don't have such level of access to the MySQL database alterative way would be using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and [JDBC Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-create-test-data-in-a-database-with-jmeter) sampler somewhere in [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) in order to execute [INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) statements per each line of the .jtl results file

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I did SET GLOBAL local_infile=1; in mysql. It's working if I tried from mysql but when I have been trying from Jmeter am getting below response.

Response body - Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

Response headers -" shared:false, driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, url:jdbc:mysql://localhost/DBName, user:Uname"